# Error: Directions

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, usage

What does "*directions*" meaning in this:

> [link](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/03/24/nyregion/hurricane-damaged-boilers-will-be-replaced-in-new-york-public-housing.html?_r=0)
>   Though the news is sure to please some residents, Mr. de Blasio, who has been fending off criticism from ***several directions*** lately, had a run-in with yet another group of protesters on Sunday: Outside the building waited several dozen Upper East Side residents who oppose the city’s plan to build a waste transfer station nearby.

It could not possibly mean real physical directions.  Other definitions for "direction" don't seem to fit this usage.
Could this be an error?

Answer (score 2):

The word **directions** is used [metaphorically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphor) here. As de Blasio's opponents occupy different positions in the "political space", either by belonging to different strata or having different beliefs, or considering different issues to be of supreme importance, they attack him, as it were, from different directions.

Comment: @meatie It's a common metaphor in English. Imagine that the criticisms are bullets instead of words and you'll pick up on the meaning. The man is being attacked by many different people from many different *directions*.